# Variable importance random forest - Is there an analog of rfpimp of Python in R to group collinear variables

Tags: python, r, random-forest

Good morning

I am using permutation importance in random forest implementation in R (`randomForest`, `caret`) to rank variables. All variables are continuous and the outcomes are categorical.

In order to deal with collinear features Terence Parr, Jeremy Howard and others have updated the `rfpimp` package in Python to group the features together which are highly correlated. That is, they state in https://explained.ai/rf-importance/#corr_collinear:

> "We updated the rfpimp package (1.1 and beyond) to help understand
>   importance graphs in the presence of collinear variables... ...As we
>   discussed, permutation feature importance is computed by permuting a
>   specific column and measuring the decrease in accuracy of the overall
>   classifier or regressor. Of course, features that are collinear really
>   should be permuted together. We have updated importances() so you can
>   pass in either a list of features, such as a subset, or a list of
>   lists containing groups..."

I could not find anything similar in the documentation of `randomForest` or of the extractor function `importance` in the package `randomForest`.

Is there an analog solution/package in R?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you can find something similar in the `randomForest` package. However you could test your correlations using something like this (http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/correlation-matrix-an-r-function-to-do-all-you-need) and then study the importance of your variable groups using the function `varImpGroup` (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RFgroove/versions/1.1/topics/varImpGroup)

Comment: Both suggestions very valuable, thx! The first one is already being processed on our side. Might actually lead "drop column importance". The second one about varImpGroup is +1 :) shall check on that one. Thx again